# Images in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, blob, indexoutofboundsexception, android-cursor, android-viewbinder

I'm trying to use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a `ViewBinder` to get an image from the database and put it into my `ListView` item view. Here is my code:

```
private void setUpViews() {
    mNewsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.news_list);

    Cursor cursor = getNews();
    SimpleCursorAdapter curAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.cursor_item, cursor,
            new String[] { "title", "content", "image" },
            new int[] { R.id.cursor_title, R.id.cursor_content,
                    R.id.news_image });
    
    ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder() {
        
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor,
                int columnIndex) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
            byte[] byteArr = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length));
            return true;
        }
    };
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news_image);
    viewBinder.setViewValue(image, cursor, cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
    curAdapter.setViewBinder(viewBinder);
    mNewsView.setAdapter(curAdapter);
}
```

I am getting:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 60
```

while executing `byte[] byteArr = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);`. Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `cursor.moveToFirst()` has not been called so the cursor is throwing `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.`

Before using a `cursor` you should always check is the cursor is empty or not by calling `cursor.moveToFirst()`. This will also position the cursor at the first position.

Answer (score 11):

I extended SimpleCursorAdapter, and while I did not use a ViewBinder here is my code for using an image stored as a blob in an sqlite database in a listview. This was adapted from an article I read [here](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/3/).

My layout file for a row is:

row_layout_two_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/select_item">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/pic"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imagedesc"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@+id/label1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:text="@+id/label2"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

The calling code

```
...
    adapter = null;
    mCursor = search();

    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    // Now create a new list adapter bound to the cursor.
    BaseAdapter adapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(this, // Context.
            R.layout.row_layout_two_line, // Specify the row template
                                                    // to use (here, two
                                                    // columns bound to the
                                                    // two retrieved cursor
                                                    // rows).
            mCursor, // Pass in the cursor to bind to.
            // Array of cursor columns to bind to.
            new String [] {"personImage", "firstName", "lastName", "title"},
            // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those
            // columns.
            new int[] { R.id.pic, R.id.label, R.id.label1, R.id.label2 });


    // Bind to our new adapter.
    setListAdapter(adapter);
...
```

ImageCursorAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Cursor c;
    private Context context;

public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = inView;
       if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_two_line, null);
       }
       this.c.moveToPosition(pos);      
       String firstName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
       String lastName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("lastName"));
       String titleStr = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("title"));
       byte[] image = this.c.getBlob(this.c.getColumnIndex("personImage"));
       ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.pic);
       if (image != null) {
           // If there is no image in the database "NA" is stored instead of a blob 
           // test if there more than 3 chars "NA" + a terminating char if more than
           // there is an image otherwise load the default
           if(image.length > 3)
           {
               iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length));
           }
           else
           {
               iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
           }
       }
           TextView fname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
           fname.setText(firstName);

           TextView lname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label1);
           lname.setText(lastName);

           TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label2);
           title.setText(titleStr);
       return(v);
}
```

}

Here is what it looks like in the end

[image]

Comment: What is the point of using an SimpleCursorAdapter and telling it the from columns, if I am going to build the View by hand in getView????

Answer (score 4):

**Contact List using ListView and SimpleCusrorAdapter with Contact Photos and Filter/Search**

I had been looking for a simpler solution and my final solution is quite closer to the one Daniel mentioned here so I thought I should share mine here. I am using Fragment to show Device Contacts as a list of names with their pictures. Result is pretty similar to that of Daniel's but is showing only names. More information can be shown very easily once you understand the code.

In my case I was fetching names and pictures from ContactsContract using PHOTO_URI so I didn't have to extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` as Daniel had to.

My example also includes filtering the list of contacts as user types in `SearchView` to find a contact

I have a Fragment called `FragmentContacts` and two Layout files, first the main Layout `frag_contacts.xml` and second for each contact row `list_row_contact`.

frag_contacts.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:padding="8dip">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/searchView"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_contactList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_ContactList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#aaaaaa"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_row_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgContact"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentContacts.java

```
public class FragmentContacts extends Fragment
implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    private ListView lv_ContactList;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    private static final String DISPLAY_NAME = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

    private static final String[] contactsColumns = {    Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.PHOTO_URI    };
    private final String contactsFilter = "(" +Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER+ "='1') AND (" + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "='1')";
    private final String contactsSortOrder = DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    private final static String[] listDisplayColumns = { DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.PHOTO_URI   };
    private final static int[] listDataViewIDs = { R.id.contact_name, R.id.imgContact };

    String[] mSelectionArgs;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_contacts, null);
        lv_ContactList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_ContactList);
        searchView = (SearchView)view.findViewById( R.id.searchView);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        mCursorAdapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter( getActivity(), R.layout.list_row_contact, null, listDisplayColumns, listDataViewIDs, 0);
        lv_ContactList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener( new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit( String query ) {return false;}
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange( String newText ) {
                if( newText.isEmpty() ) mSelectionArgs = null;
                else mSelectionArgs = new String[]{ "%"+newText.trim()+"%"};
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader( 0, null, FragmentContacts.this );
                return false;
            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader( int id, Bundle args ) {
        if(mSelectionArgs == null)
            return new CursorLoader( getActivity(), Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactsColumns, contactsFilter, null, contactsSortOrder );
        else
            return new CursorLoader( getActivity(), Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactsColumns, contactsFilter + " AND (" + DISPLAY_NAME+" LIKE ?)", mSelectionArgs, contactsSortOrder );
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished( Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data ) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset( Loader<Cursor> loader ) {
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```