# SimpleCursorAdapter how to show an image?

Tags: android, imageview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I am making an android recipes application where i use a database.
In database there is a column named" "images", where i store the **name of the file** of the picture of the recipe where i store at drawable folder.
Now i want to make a List with the recipes, showing:
1) the Title of the recipe
2) a short description
and
3) an **image** of the recipe
To do that i use a Simplecursoradaptor.

**My problem is i can not show the image.**

I want to read the file name from the column "images" and then set the image at my imageview (R.id.imageview1)

Here is my code untill now:

```
public class RecipesMainActivity extends Activity 
{

public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id"; //Intent extra key
private ListView esodaListView;  // the ListActivity's ListView
private SimpleCursorAdapter esodaAdapter; // adapter for ListView
DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(RecipesMainActivity.this);


// called when the activity is first created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes_main);
    esodaListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.esodaList);
    esodaListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewEsodaListener);

    databaseConnector.open();

    // map each esoda to a TextView in the ListView layout
    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] from = new String[] {"title","ingredients","image"}; // built an String array named "from"
    //The XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.esodaTextView, R.id.amountTextView, R.id.imageView1}; // built an int array named "to"
    // EsodaMainActivity.this = The context in which the ListView is running
    // R.layout.esoda_list_item = Id of the layout that is used to display each item in ListView
    // null = 
    // from = String array containing the column names to display
    // to = Int array containing the column names to display
    esodaAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.recipe_list_item, null, from, to);
    esodaListView.setAdapter(esodaAdapter); // set esodaView's adapter
} // end of onCreate method

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume(); // call super's onResume method

    // create new GetEsodaTask and execute it
    // GetEsodaTask is an AsyncTask object
    new GetEsodaTask().execute((Object[]) null);
} // end of onResume method

// onStop method is executed when the Activity is no longer visible to the user
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    Cursor cursor= esodaAdapter.getCursor(); // gets current cursor from esodaAdapter

    if (cursor != null) 
        cursor.deactivate(); // deactivate cursor

    esodaAdapter.changeCursor(null); // adapter now has no cursor (removes the cursor from the CursorAdapter)
    super.onStop();
} // end of onStop method

// this class performs db query outside the GUI
private class GetEsodaTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor>
{
    // we create a new DatabaseConnector obj
    // EsodaMainActivity.this = Context
    DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(RecipesMainActivity.this);

    // perform the db access
    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        databaseConnector.open();

        // get a cursor containing call esoda
        return databaseConnector.getAllEsoda(); 
        // the cursor returned by getAllContacts() is passed to method onPostExecute()
    } // end of doInBackground method

    // here we use the cursor returned from the doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
    {
        esodaAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
        databaseConnector.close();
    } // end of onPostExecute() method
} // end of GetEsodaTask class
```

I searched a lot online but i couldnt find something tha could help me.

**Can i set an image at an imageview with simplecursoradaptor or not?**

Do i have to make a custom cursor adaptor? And if i have to make a custom one how can i do it?

Comment: I know it is a very old question but as it came up in searches while I was looking for similar solution, I though I will add my two cents here...

You can set an image at an imageView with SimpleCursorAdaptor. I have used Contact pictures using PHOTO_URI to display contact's pictures without writing much code.
Please check my answer at... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37710199/1209544

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `ViewBinder` of the adapter to set the image of the `ImageView` to the value received from the DB.

```
    esodaAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean setViewValue (View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
                     if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
                         ImageView IV=(ImageView) view;
                         int resID = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(columnIndex), "drawable",  getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                         IV.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID));
                         return true;
                    }
                     return false;
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still can not do it. Where do i have to put the above code ? How should i set the columnIndex ?

Comment: How do you save images in your DB?

Comment: the images are all @drawable-mdpi and i store the file name (strings) at the column named: "image"

Comment: You save it like as string like R.drawable.xxx?

Comment: I save only the filename of the image "xxx".

Comment: i get an error at setImageResource: "the method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Drawable)"

Comment: My mistake change setImageResource to setImageDrawable as in the updated answer

Comment: That worked !! Great thanks! I still have a lot to learn... Thank you again for your time

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah Works after a bit of tweaking ); Thanks.  Also Because I know the order of the columns in the projection I put my image in column zero and added a shortsircuit to make this beast run a little faster.  If (columnIndex==0 && view.getId() == R.id.icon).