# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 in setViewBinder setViewValue

Tags: android, imageview

I have FATAL EXCEPTION Resources$NotFoundException when set image for Imageview in listview in fragment.

My table( _id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, name text,image text) //image store filename

My data

```
public void insertsomeCatalog(){
    add("Salary Money","R.drawable.salary");
    add("Saving Money","R.drawable.saving");
    add("Other Money","R.drawable.other");
}
```

**My FragmentActivity**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_thu,
            container, false);
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_thu);
    dbHelper=new MyDatabaseHelper(view.getContext());
    dbHelper.open();

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAll();


    String[] columns = new String[] {
            "name",
            "image"
    };

    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.tvname,
            R.id.imageView,

    };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(),R.layout.list_item_layout,cursor,  columns,to, 0);
    dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue (View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
            if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView) {
                ImageView IV=(ImageView) view;
                int resID = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(columnIndex), "drawable",  getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                IV.setImageDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

I have add three image salary.png, saving.png and other.png into foder drawable

**Logcatt**

```
09-28 20:45:54.692 27457-27457/com.example.lananh.da_quanlychitieu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1118)
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:693)
                                                                                     at com.example.lananh.da_quanlychitieu.ThuFragment$1.setViewValue(ThuFragment.java:144)
                                                                                     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:146)
                                                                                     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1085)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

**Update**

I show values resId  `Log.i("ResID: ", String.valueOf(resID));`

```
09-28 23:21:38.744 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.744 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.748 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.764 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.764 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.768 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.884 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.888 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
09-28 23:21:38.900 9172-9172/doan.anhchien.myapplication I/ResID:: 0
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is the problematic line `int resID = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(columnIndex), "drawable",  getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());` aka line 143, while it breaks on the next line 144 `IV.setImageDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID));
` ?

Comment: yes, i think so,but i can't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `insertsomeCatalog` provide drawable name.
eg: change `"R.drawable.salary"` to `"salary"`

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is resolve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13330711/6393280 my code based that but it not work for me.