# SQLite image blob to string

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, blob

I'm trying to get a blob from sqlite to string, please see below:

```
ArrayList<Sudentdb> list;

GridView gridView;

final String[] from = new String[] { SQLiteHelper._ID,
        SQLiteHelper.NAME, SQLiteHelper.AGE, SQLiteHelper.PROFILE };

final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.rowid, R.id.txtName, R.id.studentage, R.id.profileimageV };

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.studentfragment, null);

    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(getActivity());
    dbManager.open();

    Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_item, cursor, from, to, 0);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have tested returning only the text and it returns correctly, but with images I get a error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
```

I assume that I first have to get the image from the database?? Any help?

**EDIT**

I understand why you would think that this question is a duplicate of [SimpleCursorAdapter how to show an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330654/simplecursoradapter-how-to-show-an-image) but in that question the image is stored in the drawable folder and he is saving and calling the name of that image as a string into sqlite. In my case, the image is in the gallery and I save it as a blob into SQLite (In another activity) and now I am trying to get the blob back from the database and displaying it in a `GridView`.

So in the answer the following will not work for me:

```
int resID = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(columnIndex), "drawable",  getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
IV.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get blob as byte[] from SQLITE

```
byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(IMG_SRC));
```

then convert byte[] to bitmap using below Util method ...

```
public static Bitmap getbitmap(byte[] img) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
    }
```

Comment: Ok and how will I add each image in specific viewholder? Currently I set the text in each viewholder with SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: please look at my code `final int[] to` the image position is determined by the id of the row in SQLite

Comment: ok then you retrieve the byte [] array and id from the sqlite , use if/else condition to set the imageview ,hope it helps ,