# how to save images in database?

Tags: android, database, image

I have Database, where I have 3 columns (first `Id`,second title `String`, third image `int`). DB like contact list with photo.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, "John");
cv.put(COLUMN_IMG_OUTSIDE, R.drawable.john_photo);
db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv));
```

Then with `SimpleCursorAdapter` I fill the list from names and their photo

```
SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
String[] from = new String[] { DataBase.COLUMN_IMG_OUTSIDE,DataBase.COLUMN_TITLE};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.img, R.id.text1, };

cursor = db.getAll();
startManagingCursor(cursor);

scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ListOfItems.this, R.layout.list, cursor, from, to);
listView.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

All is work, but when i want to add record to DB and choose a picture from Galery, i don't know how to save it in DB. I think i can save path to file like `String path = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG20130222_008.jpg"`; But it is proble when i will fill list, becouse in DB image is saving like integer value. Sorry for my english =(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to save the whole image into db as blob?

See [Android How to save camera images in database and display another activity in list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941637/android-how-to-save-camera-images-in-database-and-display-another-activity-in-li)

In this case you have to write your own CursorAdapter, then see this
[Images in SimpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710565/images-in-simplecursoradapter)

Comment: I think that ican add one column in BD and save there a path to picture. Then write an own adapter where i check in what column is a image. If column integer is empty make next 
_italic_ **bold** `File imgFile = new File(path);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);`

Comment: Yes, a custom adapter is the way to go. Personally I don't prefer using blobs to store images, but storing image paths is my first choice whenever possible.